# Ionic 3 ECONNABORTED

Tags: ionic3

when running ionic3 project in browser other project gets loaded. and i got the error in command prompt like this.

```
... Uhoh. Got error write ECONNABORTED ...
Error: write ECONNABORTED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:711:26)
    at Socket._write (net.js:730:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:331:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:317:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:243:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:657:40)
    at IO.ondata (internal/streams/legacy.js:16:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at IO.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

this same error prints in command prompt 5-6 times

Comment: i am facing same, did you get any solution for this error